# Unable to send data using bluetooth on android

Tags: android, bluetooth, connectivity

I created an app for data transfer from bluetooth in android using connectthread method but unfortunately it doesnt work.The app doesn't do any work when the bluetooth device from the list is selected. Following is my main source code . Kindly guide where i am going wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OutputStream ostream;
    private InputStream istream;
    public static final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 2;
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView listViewDetected;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch, buttonOn, buttonDesc, buttonOff;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, detectedAdapter, mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;

    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
    UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
         * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
    }

    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ListItemClicked implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : " + bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
            //callThread();
            //connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if (isBonded) {
                    //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("Log", "Paired");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: " + isBonded);
     //        btSend();

            try
            {
                BluetoothSocket socket=bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
                socket.connect();
                ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                mConnectedThread.start();
                mConnectedThread.write("Hi");
                mConnectedThread.run();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

  /*  public void btSend()
    {


        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hi.txt";

        File file = new File(path);

        BluetoothSocket socket= null;
        try {
            socket = bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);
      /* ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, path);
        values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION,bdDevice.getAddress());
        values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
        Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
        getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI,values);}*/


    class ListItemClickedonPaired implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            try {
                Boolean removeBond = removeBond(bdDevice);
                if (removeBond) {
                    arrayListpaired.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                Log.i("Log", "Removed" + removeBond);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*private void callThread() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if(isBonded)
                    {
                        arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//connect(bdDevice);
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
            }
        }.start();
    }*/
    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) {
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
            //Log.i("Log", "This is: "+bool.booleanValue());
            //Log.i("Log", "devicesss: "+bdDevice.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    }

    ;


    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
            throws Exception {
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBond = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean)removeBond.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
            throws Exception {
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }


    class ButtonClicked implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.buttonOn:
                    onBluetooth();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSearch:
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                    startSearching();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonDesc:
                    makeDiscoverable();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonOff:
                    offBluetooth();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                try {
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (arrayListBluetoothDevices.size() < 1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListBluetoothDevices.size(); i++) {
                        if (device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress())) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == true) {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                }

                //ParcelUuid[] uuids= device.getUuids();
              /*  try
                {
                    BluetoothSocket socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
                    socket.connect();
                    ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                    mConnectedThread.start();
                    mConnectedThread.write("Hi");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/




            }
        }
    };

    private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void onBluetooth() {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void offBluetooth() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

   private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                    h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

          //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(String message) {
            Log.i("TAG", "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("TAG", "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
            }
        }
    }


    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }

    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case 111:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    Handler h =new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMeassage(Message msg)
        {
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
            int end = (int)msg.arg2;

            switch(msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


}
```

here is the Log:

```
11-20 16:07:58.125 222-660/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
11-20 16:07:58.135 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-20 16:07:58.135 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41648d58)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo, PID: 12248
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity$ListItemClicked.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:125)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1115)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3691)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
11-20 16:07:58.145 12248-12248/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 16:07:58.155 1670-2285/? I/KLO_Stability: [am_crash][1448015878]:[12248,0,com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo,13155910,java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException,Invalid index 3, size is 3,ArrayList.java,255]
11-20 16:07:58.165 1195-1390/? I/WhetstoneService: Receive am_crash event for pid: 12248
11-20 16:07:58.165 1195-1390/? W/KloServer: Aborted broadcast does not supprt for: com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo
11-20 16:07:58.185 942-1450/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo/.MainActivity
11-20 16:07:58.195 1670-2285/? I/libmc: received event[index:0,mask:0x80,name:data_app_crash@1448015878194.txt]
11-20 16:07:58.195 1670-2285/? I/KLO_Stability: get wanted event[mask:128, name:data_app_crash@1448015878194.txt] from the watchset
11-20 16:07:58.195 1670-2285/? I/KLO_Stability: start gathering logcat log...
11-20 16:07:58.195 1670-2285/? I/KLO_Stability: gathering logcat log done
11-20 16:07:58.315 1195-1390/? I/libmc: group sys_app_bg memory.limit_in_bytes is set to -1
11-20 16:07:58.315 1195-1390/? I/libmc: group sys_app_bg memory.soft_limit_in_bytes is set to -1
11-20 16:07:58.315 942-956/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.qualcomm.logkit for broadcast com.qualcomm.logkit/.autotrigger.AutotriggerReceiver: pid=24531 uid=10045 gids={50045, 1028, 1015, 1023, 1007, 3003, 3002}
11-20 16:07:58.455 1195-1390/? I/libmc: task pid 24531 have been add to group sys_app_bg.
11-20 16:07:58.455 1195-1390/? I/libmc: [sys_app_bg]cgroup_add_tasks max single write time: 133ms
11-20 16:07:58.455 1195-1390/? I/libmc: [sys_app_bg]cgroup_add_tasks total time consume: 133ms
11-20 16:07:58.455 1195-24535/? E/libmc: set memory.limit_in_bytes[-2] failed: Invalid argument
11-20 16:07:58.475 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread resumed
11-20 16:07:58.475 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: All controllers paused.
11-20 16:07:58.475 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread paused, waiting for signal
11-20 16:07:58.485 942-956/? V/LocationPolicy: onForegroundActivitiesChanged
11-20 16:07:58.495 24531-24531/? D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.qualcomm.logkit
11-20 16:07:58.505 24531-24531/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
11-20 16:07:58.505 24531-24531/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
11-20 16:07:58.585 24531-24531/? D/MainApp: [onCreate] 
11-20 16:07:58.585 24531-24531/? D/MainApp: [init] 
11-20 16:07:58.585 24531-24531/? D/UtilsSettings: [updateCurProfilePreference] 
11-20 16:07:58.585 24531-24549/? D/ProfileDBManager: [openDataBase] 
11-20 16:07:58.585 24531-24549/? D/ProfileDBManager: [access$000] DataBaseManagementHelper
11-20 16:07:58.595 24531-24531/? D/MainApp: [getExternalAndInternalStoragePath] external sdcard-> /storage/sdcard1
11-20 16:07:58.595 24531-24531/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive]  Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 cmp=com.qualcomm.logkit/.autotrigger.AutotriggerReceiver (has extras) }
11-20 16:07:58.595 24531-24531/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive] android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED: data_app_crash
11-20 16:07:58.615 24531-24549/? D/ProfileDBManager: [fetchProfile] 
11-20 16:07:58.625 24531-24549/? D/ProfileDBManager: [closeDataBase] 
11-20 16:07:58.655 942-1282/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 13578:com.miui.cloudservice/u0a30 (adj 15): empty for 693s
11-20 16:07:58.695 942-956/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43038228 u0 com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo/.MainActivity t6 f}
11-20 16:07:58.705 1369-1578/? D/PowerKeeperEventLogManager: notifyForegroundCompomentChanged ComponentInfo{com.miui.home/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher}
11-20 16:07:58.705 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread resumed
11-20 16:07:58.705 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: All controllers paused.
11-20 16:07:58.705 1222-1929/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread paused, waiting for signal
11-20 16:07:58.725 942-956/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:2197056
11-20 16:07:58.735 1222-1222/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42472848 time:2197064
11-20 16:07:58.915 942-955/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{42e08e00 u0 com.miui.home/.launcher.Launcher t1} time:2197241
11-20 16:07:58.925 942-955/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:2197252
11-20 16:07:58.925 942-956/? V/LocationPolicy: onForegroundActivitiesChanged
11-20 16:07:59.125 222-222/? I/AudioFlinger: setAppName(), name=[system_server], active=[0]
11-20 16:08:01.275 222-969/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xb81cbea8) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
11-20 16:08:01.445 222-969/? I/listen_hal_loader: audio_extn_listen_update_stream_status(): uc_id 1 of type 0 for Event 2, with Raise=0
11-20 16:08:01.445 222-969/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
11-20 16:08:01.465 222-969/? I/listen_hal_loader: audio_extn_listen_update_device_status(): device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 0, with Raise=0
11-20 16:08:01.705 1195-1195/? W/WhetstoneService: do not trim { PackageName :com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo Pid: 12248 Uid: 0 Start by: activity Score:50 Old score:50 state:0 mBackgroundTimeInMillis:1448015878198 WakelockCount:0 wakelogsize:0  ActivityDestroied:false Activity size: 0 PackageInfo:{WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemoFlag:5312 [,TRIMHEAPS,SOFT_RESET,ZRAM,FLAG_DEAL_SCHEDULE] Type:0[] } tasknum:13}
11-20 16:08:02.205 12328-24074/? I/BluetoothAdapterProperties: Callback:discoveryStateChangeCallback with state:0 disc: true
11-20 16:08:02.205 12024-12024/? V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver: Received: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
11-20 16:08:02.315 24609-24609/? W/: [ColorAdjust] gammamode=2, cemode=10
11-20 16:08:02.315 24609-24609/? W/: [ColorAdjust] temp_gammavalue=2, temp_cevalue=10
11-20 16:08:02.315 24609-24609/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Don't setGamma!
11-20 16:08:02.315 24609-24609/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Don't setCe!
11-20 16:08:02.315 24609-24609/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Set temp_prefer temp_ce!
```

Comment: which bluetooth device you are using on the other end?

Comment: at both the ends there are android phones

Comment: this is an arraylist index problem .java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException,Invalid index 3, size is 3,ArrayList.java,255

Answer (score 0):

this may be the probelm

you have set the RECIEVE_MESSAGE value to 2

```
public static final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 2;
```

then when you receive the data from inputstream and send it using RECIEVE_MESSAGE arg in handler

```
       bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
       h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

but in you Handler you just use 1 in switch case which actually should be 2()
so correct code should be

```
switch(msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE: // value is 2 here now
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                    break;
            }
```

test it if other things are working good you may get a message

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but now whenever i click the device i want to send message to on the paired device list, it disappears.

Comment: it means there is some other error.post your logcat